# iOS comparing geographical locations

Tags: ios, maps, coordinates

I wonder how I calculate the distance between the iPhone user position and a given coordinates stored in a plist for example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `CLLocation` method [`distanceFromLocation:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126-CH3-SW18) to calculate between two `CLLocation` objects. You can use `CLLocationManager` to get user's current location and you can create a `CLLocation` instance for the coordinates using `initWithLatitude:longitude:` initializer.

`distanceFromLocation:` returns the distance in meters.

Answer (score 1):

This is the general formula to calculate the instance between to points, in kilometers.

```
acos(sin(lat1rad) * sin(lat2rad) + cos(lat1rad) * cos(lat2rad) * cos(lon2rad - lon1rad))) * 6378.1
```

6378.1 is the approx. radius of the Earth in kilometers. Make sure you express de values in radians and not in degrees. Just in case, the easiest way to convert degrees to radians is:

```
radians = (degrees * 0.01745329) // degrees * pi over 180
```

EDIT: fixed the formula to convert between degrees and radians. Thank you [Ozzah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/597755/ozzah)!

Comment: Factor is wrong for degrees: 0.01745329 is right. If you're doing several long-distance calculations the error will probably add up.